# How do I use Capybara get, show, post, put in controller tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec2, capybara

I'm just not sure what the exact way to word it is..

This tells me 'No response yet. Request a page first.'

```
it "should list searches" do
  get 'index'
  page.should have_selector('tr#search-1')
end
```

Is it meant to be like this instead?

```
it "should list searches" do
  get 'index' do
    page.should have_selector('tr#search-1')
  end
end
```

That way doesn't seem to actually test anything though.

What's the correct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According [to this](http://blog.ardes.com/2010/4/28/capybara-and-rack-test-sessions-and-http-methods), Capybara doesn't support PUT and DELETE requests with the default driver. PUT and DELETE are usually faked with javascript to accomodate REST based architecture.

I haven't checked, but I believe that you can use PUT and DELETE with Capybara if you make it use one of it's JS compatible drivers such as Selenium.

Answer (score 5):

The `get`, `post`, etc. methods are part of the [functional test interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers) for Rails controller tests, which is a completely separate testing system. You cannot use them with Capybara.

For GET requests, use Capybara's `visit` method instead.

For other request types (POST, PUT, ...), either do what a user does and visit a page with a form to fill out and submit. Or, if you are testing an API, write a functional test for your controller without using Capybara, like so:

```
post :index
response.status.should == 200
response.body.should contain('Hello World')
```

See also Jonas's post on [why you shouldn't test APIs with Capybara](http://elabs.se/blog/34-capybara-and-testing-apis).

Answer (score 0):

You usually use `visit` with Capybara to visit pages, I think.

```
it 'should list searches' do
  visit '/'
  page.should have_selector('tr#search-1')
end
```

Comment: Check out the RubyDoc for the Rack-Test Driver though. http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/RackTest/Driver It has get, put, delete and post methods defined (as well as the usual visit). If these do what I suspect they do, they would be very useful for testing rest controllers. I just can't figure out how to use them.